# How to insert form into other html file?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm made a form that I created into another html file which contain a form elements. What I want to do is when I click one of my navigation in my `main.html`. The `option.html`(form) that containing form will insert the elements into `main.html` in the middle instead of linking it on the another tab. Example below of my draft output.

[image: Draft]

So every time the user click the navigation all the form will show in the middle. Any tips will truly appreciate :)

**main.html**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#container {
  background-color: #707070;
}
#menu {
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*Remove bullets*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#menu ul li a,
visited {
  color: #CCC;
  /*Color of text*/
  display: block;
  /*Takes up the full width available*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #707070;
  min-width: 140px;
  /*Width when hover*/
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover
/*Color of text when hover*/

{
  color: #099;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="menu">

      <ul>

        <li>

          <a href="#">Manage Books</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a>
            <li><a href="#">Add Books</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!--- end menu --->

  </div>
  <!--- end container --->

</body>

</html>
```

**option.html**

```css
.addBooks {
  clear: both;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.addBooks label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.addBooks input {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.addBooks select {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div class="addBooks">
      <h1>Add Books</h1>
      <hr>
      <form action="#">

        <fieldset>

          <label for="bookname">Book Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookname" name="bookname">

          <br />

          <label for="category">Category:</label>
          <select name="category">
            <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
          </select>

          <br />

          <label for="author">Author:</label>
          <select name="author">
            <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
          </select>

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div>
    <!--- end of addBooks --->

  </div>
  <!--- end of container --->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should be using server side code to require and include files.

Comment: Is jQuery an option. If so you can use [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do that.

Comment: Did you use templates such as ejs or jade? If you did, it's better to handle it in the html tempaltes. For exmaple, ejs use <% include %> to include the common part of several html. see this. https://github.com/tj/ejs

Comment: @youngwind no I'm just using html template.

Comment: ok. But to handle this kind of common part, templates include is a good way. Otherwise you can use iframe, but i don't think it's a good idea.@MiaLegaspi

Comment: @youngwind which part of these link? They're too many.

Comment: The common part. Such as the form,because the form is the same or similarity between those htmls. @MiaLegaspi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jQuery is an option, you can use [**jQuery.get()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Add below code to your `<head>` section of  `main.html`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu a').click(function() {
    $.get('option.html', function(data) {
      $('#form').replaceWith(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#container {
  background-color: #707070;
}
#menu {
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*Remove bullets*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#menu ul li a,
visited {
  color: #CCC;
  /*Color of text*/
  display: block;
  /*Takes up the full width available*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #707070;
  min-width: 140px;
  /*Width when hover*/
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover
/*Color of text when hover*/

{
  color: #099;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="menu">

      <ul>

        <li>

          <a href="#">Manage Books</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a>
              <li><a href="#">Add Books</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!--- end menu --->

  </div>
  <!--- end container --->
  <div id="form">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! When I'm running your fiddle it didn't show anything? :)

Comment: Because there is no `option.html`. But if you have `option.html` and `main.html` at the same location it will work.

Comment: When I clicked any of those navigation it prints out the form and if I repeatedly clicked it still printing?

Comment: @MiaLegaspi : Check the updated answer. I have added a `div` at the end of `body` and changed the jQuery using `replaceWith`

Comment: Last question hehe. What is the your of `<div id="form"> </div>` in the bottom part after my container? You really helped me so much :)

Comment: @MiaLegaspi : That's just a container to hold the markup from `option.html`

Answer (score 0):

1.Try using an **object** element:
Add below code in main(parent) html. The data="..." attribute should include your html with form.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;">
     <object type="text/html" data="**URL to page**"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
     </object>
</div>
```

2.JQuery ajax:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("another_file_with_form.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

3.IFrame is also another option but it would get tricky to manage form inside IFrame. So I don't think you should use IFrame.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Where I'm gonna insert your first step which is object element and the `jQuery.ajax()` which is the second step? :)

Comment: The code above should be put in html page in which you want other html (one with form).